# How can I read a selected column from a text file

Tags: ios, swift

hello I want to save countries,regions and cities names list in the textfile and then want to show in tableview instead from getting the list from web server. I think It would be best to show it from the textfile instead from the web service because as the speed is concerned and please let me what do you think ?

So I have planned to save countries in **countries.txt** file like this

id     name

1      Algeria

2     America

and then regions like this

id     region        country_id

1      region-name     1

and same like cities.

So I want to know if lets say I want to show the countries name. I want to read ids and names in separate variables and then show countries names in tableview and keep the reference of ids.

Comment: What do you mean by "the database"?

Comment: I mean from mysql database.. I mean instead of getting the list from the web service

Comment: If you already have a mysql database, I would suggest using it. It is designed to be fast. Don't optimize prematurely (i.e. without evidence that there's a problem).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a tab-delimited text file:

```
1<tab>Algeria<lf>
2<tab>America<lf>
...
```

Then it is trivial to read the text file as a string, split the string into lines, and split each line into its tab-delimited components. You can put that data into any data structure you find convenient: an array of dictionaries, perhaps, or an array of structs especially designed to fit this data. Through that data structure, you now have fast arbitrary access to your data.

I realize that your data is ultimately more complex than that, but my point is, you can certainly design a data structure to match it, and you can read the data and pour it into that structure. The only problem would be if the data is so huge that it can't readily be kept in memory, and it doesn't sound like you're going to have that issue.